# SUM a column when another column has equal values

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have this MySQL table:

```
id place_id area_mq n
-- -------- ------- --
1  1             50 1

2  2             90 1
3  2             20 1

4  3             10 1
5  3             10 2
6  3             10 3

7  4             20 1
8  4             20 2

9  5             15 1
10 5             25 1
```

`id` is the primary key, `place_id` stands for an area id, `area_mq` is the surface area of the place in mq.

What I have to do is find a compact query to calculate the sum of `area_mq` with these rules:

- if `n` is **equal** for the same `place_id`, then count every `area_mq` (f.ex for `place_id`=2, I count 90 *and* 20 in the sum)
- if `n` is **different** for the same `place_id`, then count `area_mq` only *once* (possible to do because for these kind of "places" the value will be the same; f.ex. `place_id`=4, there are two 20's, i sum only 20 and not 40).

In this example, my correct total would be: 50 + (90 + 20) + 10 + 20 + (15 + 25).

Can I accomplish this with a query (no code or procedures)? If requirements for n were reversed, it would be simple with a GROUP BY and a subquery... but with these conditions, I'm stuck.

Comment: is n=1 always the n value you want to use?

Comment: No @dragon112, it can be arbitrary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select place_id, sum(area_sq)/count(distinct n)
from your_table
group by place_id;
```

Tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fed0/2)

Comment: What if n is NULL? I learn that COUNT(DISTINCT) excludes null values. What I have thought is a subquery where null values are parsed to 1, but maybe there's a better idea?

Comment: Nulls are not counted. As workaround, you can use coalesce to a special value, see a test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94001/1)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your pattern all with `n = 1` is added?

```
SELECT SUM((n = 1) * area_mq) AS total
FROM table_name
```

I do a validation that either returns 1 or 0, and then I multiply it with the column value.

Comment: No I'm, sorry, here n is progressive for simplicity, but it can be an arbitrary value

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this.  Take the *sum* and the *count* of **n**, and also the *min* and *max* (maybe overkill); use that to figure out if all values of **n** are the same.  Along these lines:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN sm/cnt = mn AND sm/cnt = mx THEN sum_area
    ELSE area/cnt END
    AS sum_area
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(n) cnt, SUM(n) sm, MIN(n) mn, MAX(n) mx, SUM(area_mq) sum_area
    GROUP BY place_id
) a
```

So, say n has values of 2 and 2 => sm/cnt = mn (4/2 = 2) and mx.  If it has values of 2 and 1 => sm/cnt != mn (3/2 != 1).